Firebase Crashlytics doesn't recieve exceptions from Redmi
So I have an .net maui app for android and use firebase crashlytics in it. Somehow crashlytics recieves crashes from Samsung (s22 and a52, android 14) and don't recieve any data from Xiaomi Redmit Note 7 with android 13. One day it recieved several crashes but after that everything stopped. Also, important moment, app for samsung installed via vsstudio 2022 in release mode and xiaomi recieves app by apk
I tried to check config and permissions and didn't find any specific requests in docs, also i tried to remove google accounts from samsung? but it still send required data. So maybe there required phone settings or something like that missing?

Have you tried debugging this? It could be some other issue, Also is this what you followed to configure crashlytics? https://medium.com/stackademic/firebase-crashlytics-for-maui-and-xamarin-19938cc24f81

@FreakyAli yeap, checked your link, seems like i have same conf, but still doesn't recieve any data. App working as it should (on all devices), to test  I throw exception which crashlytics have to recieve in the begining

Interesting, so you have debugged on this device, did you find any exceptions in the device log?

@FreakyAli nope, it should work, more interesting one day firebase analytics registered this phone? but it was only once

Interesting can you check if firebase has some bugs or some support issues with redmi maybe?
